# Tabluea bubble in bubble chart

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I would like to make a chart showing assessment scores by gender.  I would like one bubble to show the % of total students for each tick on the x-axis (call this class number).  Next, I want the inner bubble to fill the first bubble based on the % of total passing grades.  I also want to break it down by gender.  The following is an illustration of what I am looking for:

[image]

There will be 2 bubbles per x-axis value (one for males and one for females).  If the proportion of passing grades for a class is greater than it's proportion of students, then the outer bubble will be larger than the inner bubble and the colors will invert (I suppose opacity will work too).

If a bubble-in-bubble is not possible, what other chart types would you recommend?  Just side-by-side bar-in-bar?

Answer (score 1):

I guess we cannot have nested bubbles in Tableau.